Linking CSS file to all sub-sites of Spring Web application
So, I stumbled into a problem with my Spring App when linking css into the html files. I put the CSS file in the correct directory (/resources/static/styles/file.css), but it is linked only to the top-level site. For Example, while im working in localhost/index the css is linked correctly. However, when i click a button that searches the database and therefore changes the URL to localhost/index/search, the css is not linked anymore. It's worth to mention that if i paste the CSS into the HTML directly using the  tag, it works just fine in the sub-sites.
I've tried to change the hierarchy of the paths in my Controllers but it did not work. Having the CSS embedded in every html file is really not the best solution for me. Thanks in advance!

Your css files are relative, when you change you browser location then it creates wrong url.
